# BLE temperature characteristic conversion

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I have a BLE app running on nrf51822 on Zephyr. Application is reading data from humidity and temperature sensor and exposes environmental sensing characteristic.
Main exposed value is temperature (uuid:2A6E).

I have trouble reading this data via Bluez on linux. With nrfConnect app everything works no problem - I connect to the device and can see temperature reading - somewhere
between 20 and 26 degrees (assigned to said uuid).

Via Bluez I can connect and read characteristic handle but the values does not make any sense to me. Here is my workflow:

```
$ sudo gatttool -t random -b <ADDR> -I
$ [<ADDR>][LE]> connect
$ Attempting to connect to <ADDR>
$ Connection successful
$ [<ADDR>][LE]> char-desc
# there are a lot of other chars here, I list the one that interests me 
$ handle: 0x0017, uuid: 00002a6e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
$ [<ADDR>][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x17
$ Characteristic value/descriptor: 2e 09
```

So I get this value, and I cannot convert this in any way I know of to something that would make sense. I am familiar with this document:
[temperature xml](https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature.xml)
but I cannot figure out how this might help me. Somehow Nordic's app can make sense out of it, and I would like to do that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature measurement follows the following rules:

- it’s in little endian format so you first need to switch it to read as 0x092e
- you convert that to decimal and you get (9x256+2x16+14) = 2350
- then the value has an implied decimal exponent of -2, which means you take the value and divide by 100

This means the value read in this case is 23.50 Celsius

Comment: I thought it's already translated to host endian... Thanks a lot, this solves my problem.